# Entity Framework and Many-To-Many mapping: update issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a many-to-many relationship mapped in my model. The **Material** entity is related to many **Color** entities and vice versa. I'm using and intermediate tabled for this (**MaterialColor**), which only has two id columns referencing each id from each table.

This is how it's configured in my **DbContext** implementation:

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<Material>().HasMany<Color>(p => p.Colors).WithMany()
           .Map(m =>
           {
               m.ToTable("MaterialColor");
               m.MapLeftKey("MaterialId");
               m.MapRightKey("ColorId");
           });
```

So far it hasn't been a problem: except that now I have another many-to-many relationship mapped to Material with entity **Printer**: the mapping is exactly configured the same way:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Printer>().HasMany<Material>(p => p.Materials).WithMany()
           .Map(m =>
           {
               m.ToTable("PrinterMaterial");
               m.MapLeftKey("PrinterId");
               m.MapRightKey("MaterialId");
           });
```

The real problem occurs when I try to create a **Printer** entity and its relationships with Material in **PrinterMaterial**, but I **don't want to insert new Materials or new Colors**, and of course, ***neither MaterialColor records***.

I've been fixing this problem little by little and managed to skip it inserting in the tables I don't want insertion into:

```
        _dbContext.Printers.Add(printer);
        foreach (var material in printer.Materials)
        {
            foreach (var color in material.Colors)
            {
                _dbContext.Entry(color).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
            _dbContext.Entry(material).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is not completely solved because **it is still trying to insert in MaterialColor**. I'm not sure how to tell EF to skip that relationship too.

I tried this:

```
        _dbContext.Entry(material).Property(m => m.Colors).IsModified = false;
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Additional information: The property 'Colors' on type 'Material' is
>   not a primitive or complex property. The Property method can only be
>   used with primitive or complex properties. Use the Reference or
>   Collection method.

which makes sense since "Colors" is a collection.

How can I tell EF to ignore that relationship?

(P.S.: loading the material with no colors is not an option)

**EDIT**: Added printer and printer.Materials initialization:

```
        var printer = new Printer();
        printer.Materials = new List<Material>();
        printer.Materials.Add(_materialService.GetMaterialById(materialId)); // this gives the material with many properties populated, like Colors.
```

Comment: Can you add the `printer` and `printer.Materials` initialization, as well?

Comment: @TaherRahgooy added.

Comment: When you save this, EF adds new Colors?

Comment: @TaherRahgooy Not anymore: it attempts to insert at MaterialColor (see relationship map above)

Comment: The material color should not be affected, because the code provided does not change it.

Comment: @TaherRahgooy actually, the _materialService.GetMaterialById(materialId) line returns a material entity with a collection of Colors... that's where the problem comes from. What I'm trying to figure out is how to tell EF to ignore that property.

Comment: There is no problem, if colors is loaded, they are not marked by changed state, they are actually unchanged and thus EF ignores them automatically

Comment: @TaherRahgooy I can guarantee you it's not being ignored. Remember: it's not trying to insert new **Color** entities, but new records in **MaterialColor**, the table configured in the first part.

Comment: I see, Did you checked the state of `_dbContext.Entry(color).State` and `_dbContext.Entry(material).State` before change them manually?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87925/discussion-between-silvestre-and-taher-rahgooy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a workaround for this, I had to remove this mapping:

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<Material>().HasMany<Color>(p => p.Colors).WithMany()
       .Map(m =>
       {
           m.ToTable("MaterialColor");
           m.MapLeftKey("MaterialId");
           m.MapRightKey("ColorId");
       });
```

And create the Entity with both fields:

```
public class MaterialColor : ICacheableEntity
{
    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
    public virtual Color Color { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
}
```

This way I can set the MaterialColor collection elements of the Material entity to **Unchanged** when I want.